# Group By on same column in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a sql table called `Employee` in which I have EmployeeID, Status and DepartmentID columns. Now I have been assigned with the task of creating a tabular report where in I need count of total employees for a department, count of Employees which are active(Status), and DepartmentID.
Getting the Count of total employees and corresponding DepartmentID is simple with a Group By clause.

```
Select count(*) as 'Total Employees',DepartmentID from Employees 
Group By DepartmentID
```

How would I get the Count of Employees with a particular Status for the same DepartmentID as the outer query?
Please let me know if you want  some more clarifications about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have column `Status` with values **active** , no need of outer query

```
   Select count(*) as 'Total Employees',
          SUM(CASE WHEN status='Active' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as TotalActiveEmployees,
          DepartmentID 
    from Employees 
    Group By DepartmentID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
Select count(*) as 'Total Employees',
COUNT(CASE WHEN status='Active' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as TotalActiveEmployees,
DepartmentID 
from Employees 
Group By DepartmentID
```